# ng-options with array object angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have data like this :

**EDIT**

I solved my problem by change to acti[0] . But now I get wrong value in select . How can I solve this

Comment: would value not be `k`?

Answer (score 2):

You just miss the `,` symbol between each element in your object.

`$scope.provinces =    [
    {
    00844:"Hà Nội",
    00848:"TPHCM",
    008418:"Hòa Bình",
    008419:"Hà Giang",
    008420:"Lào Cai",
    008422:"Sơn La",
    008425:"Lạng Sơn",
    008426:"Cao Bằng",
    008427:"Tuyên Quang",
    008429:"Yên Bái",
    008430:"Ninh Bình",
    008431:"Hải Phòng"
    }
    ]`

Answer (score 1):

Access the first object of the array

```
ng-options ="k as v for (k,v) in provinces[0]
```

demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.provinces =    [
    {
    00844:"Hà Nội",
    00848:"TPHCM",
    008418:"Hòa Bình",
    008419:"Hà Giang",
    008420:"Lào Cai",
    008422:"Sơn La",
    008425:"Lạng Sơn",
    008426:"Cao Bằng",
    008427:"Tuyên Quang",
    008429:"Yên Bái",
    008430:"Ninh Bình",
    008431:"Hải Phòng"
    }
    ]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="formDataAddress.province"
                ng-options ="k as v for (k,v) in provinces[0]"  ng-selected="">
                 </select>
</div>
```